# How to assign Firestore data to an Object without Overriding Null values?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a class like this:

```
export class Car{
    color='';
    topSpeed=0;
    wheels = 4;
}
```

in my firestore I have a document "car" with values:

```
color:red
topSpeed:230
```

(so no 'wheel' key)

then retriving and assigning data more or less like this:

```
firebaseController.getCar().subscribe(car=>{
   this.car = car
}
```

everything works fine but wheels getting overriten to "undefined" can I make it not overrite  variables in case key not exist or value of that key is null??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the spread operator:

```
this.car = { ...(new Car()), ...car };
```

This way, `this.car` will receive the default properties (thanks to `new Car()`) and then, the `...car` part will add it's own properties, but only those different from `undefined`.

However, I'd recommend you not to use a class in this case, as the `this.car` variable won't really be an instance of `Car`. If `Car` has a `honk()` method, for instance, you won't be able to do `this.car.honk()`. Maybe it would be better to use a constructor for `Car` in that case. Or, if such an object has not methods at all, use interfaces:

```
interface Car {
    color?: string;
    topSpeed?: number;
    wheels?: number
}

const defaultCar: Car = {
    color: '',
    topSpeed: 10,
    wheels: 4
};

// ....

this.car = {...defaultCar, ...car }
```

Being `car` the object returned by Firebase.